# Update Wordpress version from 4 to 5

Tags: wordpress, updates

I'm using elementor plugin which requires Wordpress 5+. Currently I have Wordpress 4.9.13 when I try to re install page goes blank and nothing happens.

Could you provide the fix or other way of updating Wordpress.

[image]

Comment: According to the screenshot you already have the latest version of WordPress though?

Answer (score 1):

Your WordPress versioning seems to be corrupted, since it's only displaying a dash right after the version info. In cases where the WordPress auto updater isn't properly working, i would recommend to manually re-install / update WordPress via FTP. You have two possibilities:

1. You manually download your *current* WP version from the official WP download page and replace the existing ones on the server with downloaded ones. This may fix your corrupted files and you can then do the core upgrade to version 5.
2. You manually download the *latest* WP version from the official WP download page and replace the existing ones on the server with downloaded ones. (This may break things, because it's a major upgrade from 4.x to 5.x)

Whatever way you choose, before starting the manual installation, you need to **make a backup of your database** (e.g. with PHPMyAdmin)! Better, create a full copy of your current installation via FTP.

---

**Manual upgrade process**

1. Deactivate all your plugins
2. Download your desired Wordpress version (see above) from the official [website](https://wordpress.org/download/releases/)
3. Unzip the downloaded file
4. Connect to your server via FTP and remove the directories *wp-admin*, *wp-includes* as well as all WordPress core files at the root level of your WP install, except for the *.htaccess*, *wp-config.php* file. We will leave your *wp-content* folder in place, to persist all your themes, plugins and uploads.
5. Upload the fresh WP core files from your extracted local folder to your server and put them right in the places, where the old files and directories lived.
6. Once all files are successfully uploaded, login to your WordPress and you will get prompted to "Update the database". Proceed with this and you're nearly done.
7. Re-activate all your plugins